# How much helium and nitrogen are used in SpaceX's Falcon 9?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, helium

How much helium and nitrogen are used on SpaceX's Falcon 9?

Comment: Nitrogen: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21346/how-many-kilos-of-nitrogen-does-falcon-9-load-for-its-first-stage-cold-gas-thru